# How to create a drop down view like Google Calendar using Toolbar?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, toolbar, dropdownbox

I am trying to create something similar to Google Calendar drop down month widget.

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

So far I have an idea that I need to use Toolbar with expandable animation but not sure that's the right direction to move into.

Comment: What's the minimum level API collapsing toolbar supports?

Comment: Its part of design support lib now so should support 2.3 and above.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was also trying to create something similar to the Google Calendar app. I've come with this implementation:
[image: Demo of implementation]

I use the [CompactCalendarView](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView) library for the month widget. And [CollapsingToolbarLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) for the drop down.

You can view the source of this implementation at GitHub: https://github.com/GerritHoekstra/CompactCalendarViewToolbar

The main layout can be found [here](https://github.com/GerritHoekstra/CompactCalendarViewToolbar/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml).

I hope this helps you further.

Comment: Hey, I checked your code and its quite similar to mine. My problem is that the expand animation of the toolbar is quite slow, yours isn't. How did you achieved this?

Comment: I created a question asking it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527357/collapsingtoolbarlayout-expand-programmatically-animation-duration

Comment: Thank you so much! The ingenious trick with the parallax multiplier gave me what I wanted.

Comment: how can I disable toolbar dragging, and control opening and closing it just from toolbar button?

Comment: I checked your solution, however I have a question. Why does the CompactCalendarView need to be in a linearlayout? Can you not implement it without one? It didn't seem to work when I WASN'T enclosing it in a linearlayout though.

Comment: @user1480019 I have a PR ready to upgrade your project to AndroidX if you give me write access : https://github.com/Louis012

Answer (score 2):

May you want to take a look to CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <CalendarView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"></CalendarView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I recommend you to follow [this awesome tutorial](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en) to implement this and other interesting things about Design Library. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one project which create dropdown view like `Google calendar` app

Use this : [Sample Project](https://github.com/jignesh13/googlecalendar)

Which is use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside it put custom calenderView

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/ann"
        app:expanded="false"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior=".MyAppBarBehavior"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap|enterAlways"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

            <!--large view -->
            <com.example.GoogleCalendar.GooglecalenderView
                android:id="@+id/calander"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
              >


            </com.example.GoogleCalendar.GooglecalenderView>

            <!--top toolbar-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:title="fkdl"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/backsupport"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/monthname"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/googlesans_regular"
                        android:text="June"
                        android:textColor="#464646"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/arrowImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/monthname"
                        android:translationX="-5dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />
                                 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.example.GoogleCalendar.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nestedView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```