# How to create action bar like Google calendar which expands on click of Spinner

Tags: android, angular-material, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I want to create the same action bar which Google Calendar app has, which contains Spinner and by clicking it the height of action bar increases and displays the selection view.

How to proceed with this? Do I need to create a custom action bar?
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Please refer the below screenshots for more details.

[image]

After clicking the Spinner:

[image]

Comment: You could use a collapsing toolbar layout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658487/how-to-create-a-drop-down-view-like-google-calendar-using-toolbar. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856522/how-to-have-a-collapsing-of-top-view-into-a-smaller-sized-view long time back and i think you should go through that in detail and modify the same

Comment: Hi @Raghunandan, these links are really helpful. Thank you.