# How to expand/collapse the AppBar like Google Calendar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658487/how-to-create-a-drop-down-view-like-google-calendar-using-toolbar) asking about how to make an app bar that can collapse/expand when clicking on a button like in the Google Calendar *(cf gif bellow)* app **but on Android**. I'm trying to do the same **but with Flutter** and I can't find resources to do it.

Just having an explanation on how to expand/collapse the `AppBar` would be sufficient.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[SliverAppBar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSc7qFzxHDw&ab_channel=Flutter) gives you an expandable appBar that behaves great with lists. But if you just want to do it like your example I would just make it with an AnimatedContainer.

```
bool show = false;

Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children:[
    AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    child: Column(
       children:[
       Row(icon, text, actions),
       if(show)
       Calender(),
       ]),
    ),
    Expanded(child: OtherContent()),
    ],
  ),
),

_toggleCalender(){
   setState((
     show = !show;
   ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will test it later, but do you have an idea of how I could accomplish my goal using an `AppBar` or `SliverAppBar`? I'd rather not reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Just search for sliverAppBar tutorial you will find a lot.

Comment: I did a lot of research before asking but all the tutorial I find are about the folding nature of the `SliverAppBar` when the user scroll but none mention how you could "expand/collapse" the `SliverAppBar` while still keeping its scrolling behavior...

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer you set the expandedHeight property. And change it dynamically to change the height of the app bar.